# JQuery - acitree

Tags: jquery, html, acitree

aciTree works but does style sheet does not work. I can click to expand the tree but the icons did not work.

My html file looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/aciTree.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/demo.css" media="all">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.aciPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.aciTree.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   
  $('#tree').aciTree({
         ajax: {
             url: 'json/sample.json'
         },
         selectable: true
     });
   
  });
 </script>
 
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="tree"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding class="aciTree" to the div element seems to fix it.